# ADODB5 (PHP): Dynamically Build Table Columns

Tags: php, adodb

I'm wanting to know how to dynamically generate the table columns in adodb5.

Here's my current code:

```
<?php
$sql = "SELECT id FROM customers";
$query = $db->Execute($sql);
$rows = $query->GetRows();
$fields = $query->fields;

foreach($rows as $row) {
    print_r($row). '<br />';
}
?>
```

The output I recieve is:

```
Array
(
    [id] => 280
)
Array
(
    [id] => 1024
)
Array
(
    [id] => 474
)
Array
(
    [id] => 476
)
Array
(
    [id] => 564
)
Array
(
    [id] => 569
)
Array
(
    [id] => 594
)
Array
(
    [id] => 385
)
Array
(
    [id] => 304
)
Array
(
    [id] => 700
)
Array
(
    [id] => 285
)
Array
(
    [id] => 205
)
Array
(
    [id] => 536
)
Array
(
    [id] => 140
)
```

I'm literally just wanting it to grab all the columns in the query and build the table headers.  So basically, I will have a table that has all the "ID"'s under one columns.  I actually want the columns labeled, so in case I have more than one columns, for example, ID, Name, Date, Comment; it would dynamically know how to make the headers for each columns.  Is this someone that can help me with?

Answer (score 0):

You first need to modify your query that gets the data rows:

```
select * from customers
```

or if you only want certain columns:

```
select id, name from customers
```

you can then iterate through the rows and see you have an object or an associative array (I forget which) that allows you to lay out your table.  For the headers you already have the `$fields` so just iterate to form the header:

```
foreach ($fields as $name) {
    echo $name;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: What if I wanted to select certain columns?